# IR remote 8879 - cannot control speed of the motor

Tags: trains, power-functions, repair, remote-control

I got the [7938](https://brickset.com/sets/7938-1/Passenger-Train) train set for my kid.
I hook up the battery to the receiver and try the IR remote [8879](https://brickset.com/sets/8879-1/IR-Speed-Remote-Control) with it.

The motor starts running/spinning, but I can not control the speed with the orange "joystick" knobs on the remote.

Whether I turn the wheel clockwise or CCW, the speed just ramps up (to the maximum speed, I guess) faster and faster.

- Fresh batteries are installed
- Same channels are selected (also tried all four channels)
- Switched between red and blue connections

Any ideas why this may be?

Comment: For what it's worth - I have seen that happen a few times with my remote as well (albeit just on one of the joysticks iirc), but couldn't reproduce it just now with several combinations of IR receivers (both v1 and v2 fwiw) and motors. I've always suspected a faulty contact, but have never found out for sure.